# Update GUI from another class in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, tcp, client, server

I'm building a server and a client for a chat that runs on Tcp and Sockets, I want the client to handle more than one connection (to servers) so I made a class called "Client" to manage the async connection, so that I can run more instances at the same time like:

```
Dim ConnectionToServer1 as new Client
Dim ConnectionToServer2 as new Client
```

Since it's async when the the "connection" receives a message it generates an event (AsyncCallback) where I can convert the received bytes into a string.

The problem is: I've tried to set this string to a RichTextBox on my Form from inside the Client class, but nothing happens, I've tried to create a delegate in the form code but nothing works, the only way I was able to put the received message in the RichTextBox is by creating a public variable called LastMessage in the Client class where the last message is stored (every time it receives a message, the sub overrides the string), and then running a thread created by the Form which keeps checking for data (since the thread has been created by the form it has access to the controls, including the RichTextBox, right?)
Although I find this a bit clunky, is there any other way (through delegates maybe?) I can do it?

Here's some code: 
Client class: http://pastebin.com/GF9um8Ss
Form code: http://pastebin.com/xW7mDj8j

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you started down all the right paths.

Now, on threaded applications one of the challenges that you will face is you can have tons of worker threads, but only the main, UI thread can actually make any updates to the UI. So keeping that in mind, if you have async code that needs to update the ui you will need to use what is effectively a delegate.

You can do this using tasks these days a lot easier, so read up on the Task Parallel Library, but essentially you need a delegate/task that is marshaled to run on the ui thread to handle the UI updates.

Comment: Thanks you so much forma your time!

Comment: No Problem. If my answer helped you solve your issue, please mark it as accepted so future searchers know this was useful.

Answer (score -1):

Set this global property as false

```
Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false
```

this will let you edit any control of your form from any thread

Comment: *DO NOT DO THIS*!!! This is 100% a bad, wrong way to try to handle this. It only disables the other warning exception, not the underlying problem.

Comment: @Tim , Can you explain what kind of problems?

Comment: Intermittent crashes, hangs, blue screens. No guarantee of stability. The only reason that option exists is to allow for temporary debugging of issues, it is not meant for production code. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.checkforillegalcrossthreadcalls%28v=vs.110%29.aspx